# Can I unlink picture fields in output Word mail merge without unlinking hyperlinks

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink, ms-word, mailmerge

I am executing a Word mail merge from MS Access VBA. The document contains both pictures and hyperlinks, which are dynamic based on the mail merge source table.

To convert the pictures, I use objWord.Fields.Unlink after executing the mailmerge, but I have recently added a dynamic hyperlink, and the code also removes those links.

To insert pictures, I use { INCLUDEPICTURE { IF TRUE "{PicturePathFromMailmerge}" } \d }

To insert hyperlinks, I have { HYPERLINK { MERGEFIELD LinkFieldFromMailmerge } * MERGEFORMAT }

My code is:

```
    objWORD.MailMerge.Execute

    Set objNEW = objWORD.Application.ActiveDocument

    objNEW.Fields.Unlink
```

So, pretty indiscriminate, but I don't have much experience of using VBA for Word docs.

How can I remove the picture links and not the hyperlink links? The pictures are contained within a table, so that may be helpful, if you could run code which selected each table and unlinked the contents?

Comment: Edit question to show procedure that unlinks. Can you use an If Then conditional to check for the link type?

Comment: Post edited to show code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't do that with field coding. A macro is required. For example, as a stand-alone Word macro that intercepts the 'Edit Individual Documents' process:

```
Sub MailMergeToDoc()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Execute
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
    If .Fields(i).Type <> wdFieldHyperlink Then .Fields(i).Unlink
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like genius.  I run the mail merge from Access using VBA, so I'll try that and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Worked like a charm, saved me pulling out the rest of my hair.  Thank you!